# excel VBA Type Mismatch in if

Tags: vba, excel

Part of my code is

```
     Set Accnumber = Range("B7:B26")

If Not Intersect(Target, Accnumber) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each rCell In Intersect(Target, Accnumber)
        If Intersect(Target, Accnumber) = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please enter account number"
            rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Else
            rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Line 5 is showing the mismatch, I believe its because the Accnumber variable is not set, but im not sure what to set it as, can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: `Intersect` function returns a Range as return type. Comparing it to String is why the problem occurs.

Comment: What is Target set to?

Answer (score 1):

If the `Intersect()` between `Target` and `Accnumber` is more than a cell, you're comparing something like `Range("A1:A5")` with `""` and this is clearly raising a type mismatch (comparing a `Range` type agains a `String`).

If you mean "if all the cells = """, then you should loop through each of them to define if they are all empty:

```
allEmpty = True
For Each cell In Intersect(Target,Accnumber)
    If cell <> "" Then 
        allEmpty = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell
```

Hence, performing your test on a `Boolean` basis. This will work both if the intersection is one single range or many.

```
If allEmpty Then
    MsgBox "Please enter account number"
    rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
```

But reading your code and seeing you weren't expecting this, then I think you should revise the way `Target` is define, maybe you want to control what range the user is selecting since it seems you're expecting this intersection being at most one cell (at least this is what I guess from the text of your `MsgBox` and from the fact you're comparing agains `""` because you expect to access the default `Value` property of the `Range` class, something you can do only when the `Range` is single).